# Why my computer is not able to use Full Ram?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, ramdisk

I have Windows 7 Pro 32 bit. having 4 GB Ram and only 932 Mb is usable.
Why is that ?

My system configuration -

[image: My system configuration]

Comment: Why are you using the 32-bit edition with Core i3 (which fully supports x86-64)?

Comment: i am using a 32bit software given by my company

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common problem with some HP systems judging by [this thread in their support forums](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Installed-memory-4GB-932MB-Usable/td-p/2552171).

Users in that thread have had varying success with adjusting BIOS settings and/or updating the BIOS to a new version *(version f.12 seems popular, but the version will probably vary depending on your model)*.  Skimming over the thread briefly it seems that the following fix may give you access to a larger chunk of the memory:

In your BIOS you can try disabling features like those below that may reserve some of your memory for other purposes:

- Hybrid graphics
- Thunderbolt

[This Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/978610) may also have some BIOS settings that will be relevant.